# Fast feature selection on a huge dataset in R on a term document matrix

Tags: r, classification, feature-selection, natural-language, bag-of-words

I have a 500K rows x 10K features dataset.

It consists into :

- a term document matrix with words + bigram and TF-IDF weighting
- 6 one hot encoded multi-labels

It is much more features that I want to train for the classification tasks.

I will train several models but I need to reduce the the dimensionality first, while keeping the word per word explainability.

I have several feature selection algorithms in mind that I could apply prior to any classification algorithm.

- Chi Square
- ANOVA
- Univariate
- LASSO
- Backward propagation
- Random forest based
- ...

I'm not experienced with such hudge BoW dataset. I was wondering if some of you had this experience and could tell me what feature selection methods could run fast and get good results?

Thanks

Comment: No solution here, but I have found that often BOW representations suffer from very very sparse columns (this means the word is often used once of twice in the corpus).  I've had good success pruning the minimum document frequency (and maximum document frequency too since a large df means the word appears too often and hence may not give much information).  Its a good way to cut down on a couple hundred to maybe a thousand features.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. I found it surprisingly useful too, yet accuracy keep raising when I had features. Currently I think into adding an average of the word2vec vectors to capture missing information at the end of the BoW and to reserve words extraction to the most relevant ones. 

Also, interestingly, using findCorrelation from Caret with high values like 0.999 already prune a significant amount of features.